# Chrome 71 will refuse to execute script because its MIME type ('text/x-js') is not executable

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mime-types, web-worker

I am facing an issue on **Chrome 71**:
in FireFox it works fine, also on Chrome < v71.  There was an [announcement at Google](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/10/tweaks-to-addAll-importScripts) that we should expect two small changes in our way of working with **service  workers** and **cache storage api** .
But the new version breaks my importScripts and I do not know how to solve it yet.

I got a file named `pdfmake-worker-blob.js` which makes an:

```
importScripts('./pdfmake.min.js');
importScripts('./vfs_fonts.js');

onmessage = function(req) {

  pdfMake.fonts = {
      Courier: { normal: 'cour.ttf',bold: 'cour-bold.ttf' },
      Arial: { normal: 'arial.ttf',bold: 'arial-bold.ttf' }
  };

  try {
    var pdf = pdfMake.createPdf(req.data);
    pdf.getBlob(function(output) {
        postMessage(output);
    });
  } catch(err) {
    throw err;
  }
}
```

Then we create the worker in another service like this before using it:

```
 var pdfmakeWorkerBlob = new Worker('scripts/pdfmake-worker-blob.js');
```

And you can see this in chrome debugger mode(let me remind you once again that the code works fine on **firefox** and **chrome 70** and below I guess): 
[image]

With the following messge in the console and my worker doesn't do his job anymore:

> pdfmake-worker-blob.js:1 Deprecated: Future versions will refuse to
>   execute script from
>   'http://myserver_name.company.com/application_name/scripts/pdfmake.min.js'
>   because its MIME type ('text/x-js') is not executable.

I did not set this Mime type or any i just did an importscripts that is all. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: can you show us more of your worker code? is the importScripts call asynchronously inside a handler in the way the article says it cannot be anymore?

Comment: Why are you setting that mime type?

Comment: @Josh Lee: I did not.  i just do i importscripts

Comment: @LShaps It is not an asynchronous call. I will show more code to give more context

Comment: @Novy The browser clearly thinks you are setting the MIME type to something invalid. Please include what you are actually setting it to in the question.

Comment: There was something wrong about apache configuration. But the fact that it did work on chrome 70 and mozilla is a problem i guess in a kacking perspective. Thank you for your help and your time @Josh Lee

Comment: Thank you for the help @LShapz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who is facing the problem it is a well konown issue: "**strict MIME type checking**". Chrome enables strick mime type checking. There is ton of questions on stack over flow about it. 
But it happens that it was still possible to avoid "**strict MIME type checking**" through worker api with importScripts.

For those who are still using chrome 70.0.3538.110 like me there is no strick mime type checking through the  **importScripts** on the worker api. The new version of chrome fixes it. But it is still possible in firefox. I reported [this behaviour](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1516233) to mozilla in case it was not expected

It was not clear for me but in our production machine our apache server has this mime type set: **"text/x-js js"**. I simply replace it with application **"application/javascript"** js instead or **"text/javascript js"** which is obsolete by the way.